# How can i enable and disable GPS programatically

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an application wherein I want to enable GPS, when I start my activity and I want to disable GPS when I exit my application. Can I do it through my program..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no supported way to enable/disable GPS from an SDK application. Every technique that purports to do this is a security hack, and all known ones have been closed. Please allow the user to enable and disable GPS themselves using the Settings application or a device-supplied app widget.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a way to allow the user to authorize your app to do this automatically?  The idea would be to allow the app to disable the GPS when the app is not using it to conserve power and then enable it only when it needs to use it.

Comment: @gonzobrains: "Is there a way to allow the user to authorize your app to do this automatically?" -- nope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code...

```
 private void turnGPSOn(){   

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);   
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){      
        final Intent poke = new Intent();  
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");           poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);   
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));      
        sendBroadcast(poke);  
   }  }
```

Comment: Will the above method enable or disable GPS in android mobile.

Comment: I think there's a clue in the name of the function.

Comment: Reportedly, this code no longer works, as it is a security hole.

Comment: @Sujit Can you please say me how can I turnoff  GPS?

Comment: you can just remove the "!" from if block and rest is name and use it as a different method name say turnGPSOff() and called it whenever you want to disable the GPD. It is a actually a bug in the power manager widget still you can use it .

Answer (score 6):

You can start the GPS by using

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new CTLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1.0f, locationListener);
```

To stop the gps provider use

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

I researched about this subject on all web sites. and I found this code like below. I tried its working.

Method-1

```
Enable GPS
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
Disable GPS
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Method-2

```
 // If GPS is OFF
    private void turnGPSOn(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
    // If GPS is ON
    private void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(provider.contains("gps")){
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

Fore more information you can visit this web site : http://androidmaterial.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-enabledisable-gps-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is all I can find (my code doesn't run in an activity so I have an ApplicationContext class that I call a static method getInstance. You don't have to do this in an activity. Sorry for the code formatting):

```
public static boolean isGPSEnabled(){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)ApplicationContext.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );
        if(enabled) return enabled;
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return provider.contains("gps");
    }

private static boolean canToggleGPSDirectly() {
        PackageManager pacman = ApplicationContext.getInstance().getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pacInfo = null;

        try {
            pacInfo = pacman.getPackageInfo("com.android.settings", PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false; //package not found
        }

        if(pacInfo != null){
            for(ActivityInfo actInfo : pacInfo.receivers){
                //test if recevier is exported. if so, we can toggle GPS.
                if(actInfo.name.equals("com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider") && actInfo.exported){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false; //default
    }

//this only works in older versions of android (it woks on 2.2)
private static void toggleGPS(){
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        ApplicationContext.getInstance().sendBroadcast(poke);
    }

private static void showGPSSettingsScreen(){
        //show the settings screen
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ApplicationContext.getInstance().startActivity(myIntent);

        // this doens't work if your app isn't signed as firmware....Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(ApplicationContext.getInstance().getContentResolver(), LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    }

public static void ensureGPSStatus(boolean on){
        boolean isGPSEnabled = isGPSEnabled();
        if((isGPSEnabled && !on) || (!isGPSEnabled && on)){
            if(canToggleGPSDirectly()){
                toggleGPS();
            }else{
                showGPSSettingsScreen();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Disable the GPS through your code,

```
    Intent my_intent = new Intent();
    my_intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    my_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    my_intent.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
     sendBroadcast(my_intent);  //use context.sendBroadcast(my_intent) if you are in any Broadcast activity
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you can't do it entirely programmatically. The best is to fire an intent to start the settings page but subsequently user must enable the gps setting in the settings page.

You can't do it in the background without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but directly starting location service will not work. Instead use below code to start location service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**GpsSettings**

```
public class GpsSettings
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void turnGPSOn(Context context)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");

        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);  

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(context.getContentResolver(), "gps", true);

        if (!provider.contains("gps"))
        {
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            context.sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void turnGPSOff(Context context)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");

        intent.putExtra("enabled", false);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);  
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (provider.contains("gps"))
        {
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            context.sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
}
```