# How to stop or disable GPS after 15 minutes when my application launched in android device?

Tags: android, gps

I would like to disable GPS on an Android device 15 mins after my application launches. Could anyone give some sample code or some ideas?

Comment: please share what you have tried so far!!

Comment: [enable-and-disable-gps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138187/how-can-i-enable-and-disable-gps-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [CountDown Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way.

```
// 15 * 60 * 1000 = 900000 
new CountDownTimer(900000, 1000) 
{

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an alarm with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).